# Scroll to a particular date in Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there a way which I can select a particular date or a date range in Whatsapp and view those messages under those specific date(s)?

Comment: I don't think WhatsApp has implemented such functionality. But you can search for specific word and every message containing that word will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhatsApp search features as of now don't have this kind of search for.

I required this feature some months ago to search based on dates and content. Googling led me to *Bag a Chat* app ( can't link it from play store since it is not available on my country). I download from [apkpure](https://apkpure.com/) , used the app for a few days and uninstalled it ( Two reasons - it was a one time requirement for me and second, because of the permissions it wanted)

From memory, you need to save the chats you want to search using the app and filter them based on your search needs. You can search based not only on dates but many other parameters as [explained](http://bagachat.com/central_backup.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can also do the following without using an extra app specialized on searching through WhatsApp.
Go to options (the "..." symbol) -> "more" -> "send chat per email". This way you can export a txt file including date, time and message content and send it per e-mail. This file can be imported to excel or smth and filtered using normal functions of the program you import it to.

Comment: Do u know how far back does the log goes??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a go to date feature but it will get you close and uses the standard whatsapp app.  Look at the media in a chat (3 dots, "Media, links, and docs") and when you move the scrollbar slider it will show the month and year so you can use that to quickly jump close to the date you wanted.  Then open up one of the media items, click the 3 dots, and select "Show in chat".  You'll be on the date the media item is from which is hopefully close to the date you wanted to look at.

For greater accuracy you can swipe through the media items before selecting "Show in chat".  It will show the date at the top of the screen which should let you find something closer to the date you wanted.  This second option might help you get there faster with less scrolling but it kind of depends on how often you have media in this chat and how many messages you might need to scroll through.  It might be faster to just jump to the right month and start scrolling a little.